# Call macro if autofill is used on a worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

i try to implement a auto-start of a macro, if the autofill function is used on a worksheet.

Is there any special term like "Sub Worksheets_AutoFill" to start a macro?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe even the `Worksheet_Change` event... Though I don't know much about AutoFill...

Comment: Thanks for your comment. For better understanding: There is a main Worksheet, which contains meetings, which are linked to hidden worksheets. If a meeting is expanded over several days via autofill, then every worksheet should do the same... 
I just don´t know, how this event could call a macro.

Comment: `Worksheet_Change` event then.

Comment: Thanks SamuelEverson  &  BigBen, however, now the macro is also called, if I add some content in cells. It should only be called, if autofill is used.

Comment: There's no macro trigger event that only runs for autofill. From a macro point of view, autofilling 5 cells is no different than 5 cells being changed. You'll need to use the `Worksheet_Change` event, like others have mentioned, then filter out to only run your code if the changed cells are in the range you're interested in.